# How to get X, Y coordinates in 2D drawing of Forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I would like to get the X and Y coordinates of a 2D drawing on mouse click. Then I can draw something on top of this 2D drawing. Here is the code to get the coordinates on mouse click but it is not correct.

```
viewer.impl.canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
    // Get 2D drawing dimension
    var layoutBox = viewer.impl.getVisibleBounds();
    var width = layoutBox.max.x - layoutBox.min.x;
    var height = layoutBox.max.y - layoutBox.min.y;

    var viewport = viewer.impl.clientToViewport(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    var point = [viewport.x * width, viewport.y * height, viewport.z];

    // Show the 2D drawing X, Y coordinates on mouse click
    console.log(point);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this using a [custom viewer tool](https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2015/03/creating-tools-for-the-view-data-api.html):

```
handleSingleClick (e, button) {

    var hitTest = this.viewer.clientToWorld(e.canvasX, e.canvasY, true)

    if (hitTest) {

        console.log(hitTest.point)
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! This is what I am looking for. Thank you Philippe!